# C# SOAP v1.0 project with WS-Encryption & WS-Signing

Tags: c#, soap, soapui, soap-client

I have been tasked with a job to create an app that connects to a web service that uses Soap V1.0 with WS-Security.

I have been able to connect successfully using Soap UI. The Soap Service is sent via HTTPS, the SOAP message must be signed with a x509 cert and the soap body must be encrypted with their SSL.

The Working SOAP XML looks like this:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns="http://www.qwerty.com/esi/common/1.0" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958150741">
                    <wsu:Created>2016-04-06T05:13:01.507Z</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires>2016-04-06T05:46:21.507Z</wsu:Expires>
                </wsu:Timestamp>
                <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958150539" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
                    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                            <ds:X509Data>
                                <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=abc CA asd,O=qwerty ,L=Sydney,C=AU</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>2334442322</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                            </ds:X509Data>
                        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                    <xenc:CipherData>
                        <xenc:CipherValue>SAulApKrrr5M+Fhy5VWKkAug..cut for readability</xenc:CipherValue>
                    </xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:ReferenceList>
                        <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958150540"/>
                    </xenc:ReferenceList>
                </xenc:EncryptedKey>
                <ds:Signature Id="SIG-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958145938" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa ns soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                        <ds:Reference URI="#id-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958145837">
                            <ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ns" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                </ds:Transform>
                            </ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                            <ds:DigestValue>TRGWcb2SG5CRTP1FC4U1tvqg=</ds:DigestValue>
                        </ds:Reference>
                    </ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:SignatureValue>Nnl7..cut for readability</ds:SignatureValue>
                    <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958145835">
                        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958145836">
                            <ds:X509Data>
                                <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=query =qwerty ,L=Sydney,C=AU</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>105asdsa571845470</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                            </ds:X509Data>
                        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                </ds:Signature>
                <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958145533">
                    <wsse:Username>myusername</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mypassword</wsse:Password>
                    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">nonce==</wsse:Nonce>
                    <wsu:Created>2016-04-06T05:13:01.454Z</wsu:Created>
                </wsse:UsernameToken>
            </wsse:Security>
            <wsa:Action>http://www.qwerty.com/esi/common/1.0/getAuthenticationExpiryRequest</wsa:Action>
            <wsa:MessageID>urn:dill:Software Version:1</wsa:MessageID>
            <wsa:To>http://www.qwerty.com/esi/common/v1</wsa:To>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958145837" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958150540" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-1D010A91DEF5E45ACE145991958150539"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>HEf6zyUibGuAjgUY/cut for readability</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedData>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

My Very flawed response sent via C#

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_1">http://www.qwerty.com/esi/common/1.0/getAuthenticationExpiryRequest</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID u:Id="_2">urn:uuid:8531ad33-56fd-4575-ba3b-cc237617f5f8</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo u:Id="_3">
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo5YvIPcIlqZNsE+PcW7SWU3jm5ZcyzThspFKp7rCG5JTJikACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4">http://it02:8080/esi2/esi-gateway/common/v1</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-f39da944-9f7f-4c48-ad90-69442f958db5-1">
                <u:Created>2016-04-06T05:08:02.239Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2016-04-06T05:13:02.239Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-1892a0d2-1f61-4c02-b91b-b969e8ee1d44-1">
                <o:Username>My Username</o:Username>
                <o:Password>MyPassword=</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
            <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-1892a0d2-1f61-4c02-b91b-b969e8ee1d44-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">MIII3Q==</o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_1">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>qBpW9R+T2WBBySN4iBskNiWs7lk=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#_2">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>gyelv9es6SoTBFgujy2Qilngr1Y=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#_3">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>o3ibE52LCPwycD7dwAsKtJa+WMw=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#_4">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>s2MW+MnmlKI4VtLdAY6vEZbxoco=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#uuid-f39da944-9f7f-4c48-ad90-69442f958db5-1">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>7UO6LSMnFDePv9O88EiFigXEAiM=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#uuid-1892a0d2-1f61-4c02-b91b-b969e8ee1d44-1">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>ri+XlD6yZMrBP2N4mSO0t/8g9Po=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#uuid-1892a0d2-1f61-4c02-b91b-b969e8ee1d44-2">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>WZH8tnKlq/XPoUn5KkoqZzdKrdE=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>S8U........</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier">FM69HI68yR5C/F5e/WRIHII7BAM=</o:KeyIdentifier>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <AuthenticationExpiryRequest xmlns="http://www.qwerty.com/esi/common/1.0"/>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My C# Code thus far:

```
class Program
    {

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetCustomBinding()
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement asbe = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
            asbe.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12;

            asbe.InitiatorTokenParameters = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
            asbe.RecipientTokenParameters = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
            asbe.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.EncryptBeforeSign;

            asbe.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
            asbe.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
            asbe.IncludeTimestamp = true;
            asbe.SetKeyDerivation(false);
            asbe.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128;

            asbe.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());
            asbe.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters());

            CustomBinding myBinding = new CustomBinding();
            myBinding.Elements.Add(asbe);
            myBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8));            
            HttpTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
          //  httpsBindingElement.RequireClientCertificate = true ;


            myBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);

            return myBinding;
        }

        private static void SetClientCredentialsSecurity(ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
        {
             var store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
            X509Certificate2 esiCertificate = new X509Certificate2();

            foreach (var cert in store.Certificates)
            {
                if (cert.FriendlyName.Contains("certname"))
                {
                    certificate = cert;

                }
                if (cert.SubjectName.Name.Contains("certname"))
                {
                    esiCertificate = cert;
                }


            }



            clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "asd";
            clientCredentials.UserName.Password = "asd";

            string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            clientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = esiCertificate;
            clientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;

        }

        private static ServiceReference1.Common10Client GetCredentialingClient()
        {
            ServiceReference1.Common10Client client = new ServiceReference1.Common10Client(GetCustomBinding(), new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://asd/esi2/esi-gateway/common/v1"), new DnsEndpointIdentity("esiServer"), new AddressHeaderCollection()));
            client.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None;
            SetClientCredentialsSecurity(client.ClientCredentials);

            return client;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                using (ServiceReference1.Common10Client client = GetCredentialingClient())
                {
                    client.Open();

                    ServiceReference1.getAuthenticationExpiryRequest request = new ServiceReference1.getAuthenticationExpiryRequest();
                    request.AuthenticationExpiryRequest = new ServiceReference1.AuthenticationExpiryRequest();

                    client.getAuthenticationExpiry(request.AuthenticationExpiryRequest);
                }


        }
```

as you can see they are very different. What I need is:
WS-Security - Encryption, Username, Timestamp, Signature.

But I'm unsure how to replicate it in C#

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the SOAP classes included in WSE as a base?

Comment: check this one. May be helpful to you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996945.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just reading over what you've asked, I'd say to have a read through [Generating XML Documents from XML Schemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx) and point your schema at the xsd referenced in the original.  If that proves too cumbersome, take apart the xsd and instead of manipulating this as xml, manipulate it using a string-builder and shove *that* down the pipe.

Are you getting errors because of the format not matching up?  Or are you getting errors due to the encryption?  Can you post them?